# Need GTK# 64bit library

Tags: mono, gtk#

I am trying to create a 64bit Gtk GUI with the GTK# library and am not having much luck.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008, version 3.5 of C#.  I obtained version 2.8.5 of the GTK# source and modified the makefiles to compile 64bit.  I compiled this source against the 64bit version of GTK+ v2.22.  The source compiled and I was able to import the "sharp" DLLs into my VS project.

When I try to run my app, it complains that it's trying to load a 32 bit GTK assembly.  I altered the makefiles to use the 64bit versions of MinGW compiler and dllwrap and added the /platform:x64 directive to calls to CSC.exe.  I am at a loss.  I must be missing another flag/directive for 64bit somewhere.

Has anyone else tried to compile GTK# for 64bit?  Does anyone know of a place to download precompiled 64bit versions?

I'm pulling my hair out trying to make this work.  I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Steve---